# Is having models with ever increasing cardinality of the power set of $\omega$ is a theorem of ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

I'll present this claim informally and try to write it formally as much as I can.

Statement: every model of $\sf ZFC$ that statisfies the statement that the power set of $\omega$ is equal to a specific $\aleph_{\alpha}$, there is another model of $\sf ZFC$ that satisfies the statement that the power set of $\omega$ is strictly bigger than $\aleph_{\alpha}$.

$\forall x \forall M [(M \models ZFC + |P(\omega)|=x) \to \\ \exists y > x \ \exists  N (N \models ZFC +  |P(\omega)|=y)] $

> Question: is the above statement a theorem of ZFC?

Comment: What if $\phi$ is $x=|P(\omega)|$?

Comment: @EricWofsey, I've made an edit. Thanks

Comment: What does $M\models |P(\omega)|=x$ mean, if $x$ is an arbitrary set?

Comment: @EricWofsey, I had the impression that any particular "substitution" of the variable $x$ would be seen by the model substituting the variable symbol $M$ as a constant. For example when $x$ is $\omega_1$, then the model satisfying $|P(\omega)|=\omega_1$ would so and so.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Again, you're conflating theories and objects: if $\alpha$ is an arbitrary ordinal in some model $M$ there's no reason for "$2^\omega=\aleph_\alpha$" to be in any sense expressible by a first-order sentence in the language of set theory. So while we can ask whether that expression is satisfied in a structure containing $\alpha$, it doesn't make sense to ask whether ZFC proves it (or anything involving it).

I think the right way to ask the intuitive question you have in mind is:

> Does ZFC prove that, whenever $M\models$ ZFC and $\alpha\in Ord^M$, there is some $N\models$ ZFC with $Ord^M=Ord^N$ and $N\models 2^\omega>\aleph_\alpha$?

If we add the assumption that $M$ is countable, this is easy: forcing over arbitrary countable models can be formalized inside ZFC, so just consider the forcing adding $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$-many Cohen reals.

For uncountable models, however, the statement is clearly false: we could have an $\omega$-model which literally contains every real, so we clearly can't push the continuum any higher.

Comment: Of course, if one replaces model with "Boolean-valued model", then uncountability is no longer a problem.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Quite right of course.

Comment: Also we need to add both assertions of countability of $M$ and of $N$.

Comment: I don't see $M \models |P(\omega)|=\aleph_{\alpha}$ mentioned in your statement? I think it should be added before the second comma in your statement

Comment: @Zuhair It doesn't need to be: $\alpha$ is an arbitrary element of $Ord^M$, whether $\aleph_\alpha=2^\omega$ in $M$ or not. So in particular we *could* add that hypothesis, but that would actually weaken the statement.

Comment: @Zuhair Re: your first comment, I did add the assumption that $M$ is countable ("If we add the assumption that  is countable"). Requiring $N$ to be countable, though, isn't necessary: any set forcing extension of $M$ will also be countable, so we get that for free.

Comment: You said something about non-expressibility of an arbitrary set in the language of set theory, that is true, but it would be expressible if we extend the language of ZFC by adding that ordinal $\alpha$ as a constant!

Comment: @Zuhair You can't add objects as constants at the theory level - that only makes sense at the *model* level. E.g. if $A,B$ are two structures in a given language with disjoint domains and $\varphi$ is a formula in that language, then for $a\in A$ we have that $\varphi(a)$ does make sense in $A$ but doesn't make sense in $B$.

Comment: according to that you must also state that $\omega \in dom(M)$ and $\omega \in dom(N)$

Comment: @Zuhair Yes, that's an abuse of notation on my part: conflating the symbol "$\omega$" with the obvious *formula defining* $\omega$. That is, when we say (for example) "ZFC proves that $2^{\omega}$ has uncountable cofinality," what we mean is "ZFC proves that the powerset of *the smallest infinite ordinal* has uncountable cofinality." It's just that that's a pain to write out, so we use the symbol "$\omega$" as a proxy.